# Task returning before its completion

Tags: c#, winforms, task, task-parallel-library, desktop-application

I have desktop application in which I am doing some SQL Server queries asynchronously using ADO.NET. There is one case in which I am creating an object and its taking around 5-6 seconds for completion. Now the problem is occurring when I am calling a ADO.NET asynchronous method to fetch data from database. Once it hit `await` then call is return to main thread without completing other tasks and after some it returning back await but the call is already returned to main thread, due to this I am not getting complete data.

Here is a main caller:

```
Task.Run<Product>(() => product.GetProduct(item))
                            .ContinueWith(task =>
                            {
                                if (task.IsFaulted)
                                {
                                    throw;
                                }
                                else if (task.Result != null)
                                {
                                    // here it coming without completing a complete Task
                                }
                            })
                            .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

GetProduct methods do some more similar Task

```
public async Task<Product> GetProduct(ProductVariant item)
{
    Product product = new Product();

    product.Quantity = await GetQuantity(item.Id);
    // some other properties

    return product
}
```

The code when it hit it returned to the above task:

```
public async Task<List<Item>> Test()
{
    // preparing query code

    sqlDataReader = await sqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync();

    // code logic after result returned
}
```

How can I make it so that returned a complete Task?

Comment: Can you show how `product.GetProduct` is related to `Test`?

Comment: Don't use `ContinueWith`, use `await`.

Comment: Your method `Test` is not returning anything, especially no Task

Comment: @milbrandt I show that line. It actually returns a query result

Comment: @Fildor It's a synchronous method.

Comment: "await the result of Task.Run", I meant.

Comment: ^^ So, you mean your _caller_ is synchronous and you cannot change that ... that's complicating things.

Comment: That's really bad. Can you use synchronous API towards your DB? It's really really tricky to go from sync to async and back.

Comment: @Fildor this is the reason of using ContinueWith

Comment: I see but as you see, it doesn't work because you would have needed to do `Task.Run<Product>( async () => await product.GetProduct(item))`

Comment: It's hard to determine the workflow of this code -- When / where is `Task.Run<Product>(() => {...}` called and what calls it? - Still unclear what the role of `Test()` is here and how it relates to the previous snippets. Try to post a homogeneous, coordinated example that we can use to replicate the issue, which includes a description of why you used `.ConfigureAwait(false)` in the first snippet

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code and the comments you should `await product.GetProduct(item)` call plus I don't know the need of creating a Task (Task.Run and await it) just for it when you probably need the returned Product synchronously.

Your best bet is:

```
Product retProduct = await product.GetProduct(item);

if (retProduct != null)
{
    // Do your logic
}
else
{
    // Handle it
}
```